# Understanding EJS in node.js/express

Tags: node.js, express, ejs

I am new to node.js, and using EJS is giving me a hard time. I am so used to HTML/jQuery. But I am not able to make jquery work with EJS.

when I try to use http get/post in EJS via form action it works. 
Anything else doesn't work.

```
**HTML**
<head>
    <title><%= title %></title>
</head>
<body>
<h1><%= title %></h1>
<p>Welcome to <%= name %></p>
<div>
    <form action="/room1/getTemp" method="get">
        <input type="submit" id="getTempBtn" value="Get Temperature"/>
        <label>Temperature is: </label>
        <input type="text" id="tempID" value= <%= temperatureValue %>>
    </form>
    <div id="div1">
    <input type="button" id="getDistance" value="Get Distance">
    <input type="text" id="distTxt" value= <%= distanceValue %>>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
<- script written here ->
```

**SCRIPT 1**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="../node_modules/ejs/ejs.min.js">    </script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudfare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js">
<script>
    $('#distTxt').on('click',function(){ //some code which is not getting called});
</script>
```

PROBLEM: this doesn't work as browser shows an error that $ in not defined.

**SCRIPT 2**

```
Even when i  bind onclick listener to the button:
<input type="button" id="getDistance" value="Get Distance" onclick="getDis();">
<script>
    function getDis(){
        //ajax send request
        console.log('not working');
    }
</script>
```

This simple onclick doesn't work too.
Is there something very basic i am missing out on?

Question2. Is there an elegant way of using ajax calls in ejs?

Question3. Why is jQuery not working with EJS?

Comment: instead of using $, try using jQuery('#distTxt'), and see if that works. I am just trying to narrow things down

Comment: you spotted it right, there is some internal conflict when using $ symbol. 
Thanks!